# Store all numpy matrix rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, matrix, rows

For a given example, suppose we have a matrix with shape of (1000,20), my aim is to store all (1000,) in a data frame. Is there any solution to do it ? and how can I just define the (1000,) with numpy ?

I'm not sure if what I'm proposing is feasible or not. But I'd appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: you can pass any 2d numpy array to the pandas dataframe constructor and specify the column names... `a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) ; d =  pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use panda DataFrame
see the link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

class pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)

the data can be numpyarry

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, this is not my concern. I'm not looking for storing all numpy matrix in a dataframe. I'm just concerned with the first shape, i.e., (1000,). If you have any solution on how can I get it with numpy, I would appreciate it. I tried ````matrix.shape[0] and then it returns just a 1000 number while my aim is to get the numpy array (1000,)````

Comment: @Andrea, try `matrix.shape[:1]`, this should return a tuple of a single element, rather than an integer. you can also do `(matrix.shape[0],)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a random (1000,20) dataframe:

```
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,20))
df.columns = ['col'+str(i) for i in range(1,21)]
df.shape

(1000, 20)
```

You can extract a (1000,) numpy array from any column

```
>>> df['col1'].values
array([3.74540119e-01, 6.11852895e-01, 1.22038235e-01, 3.88677290e-01,
       8.63103426e-01, 3.14291857e-02, 8.07440155e-01, 9.62447295e-01,
       3.67783133e-01, 3.41066351e-01, 6.42031646e-01, 6.57612892e-01,
       ...
       7.14769358e-01, 9.29802764e-02, 9.46508378e-01, 4.98407543e-01,
       9.90723911e-01, 7.33644065e-01, 9.46458095e-01, 2.17144158e-01,
       3.38970837e-01, 9.19645673e-02, 5.22083809e-01, 8.89960122e-01])

>>> type(df['col1'].values)
numpy.ndarray

>>> df['col1'].values.shape
(1000,)
```